# Why is my htaccess not working on my web server (but it works fine locally)?

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I have the following htaccess file for my website, http://academy.young1.org.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

However, although it is working perfectly on my local server (localhost) and redirecting to the correct pages despite the '.php' extension not being present in the URL, it is not doing this at all when I load it up to the web server. It is currently stored in the same ftp subdirectory as my main php files, ftp://ftp.young1.org/academy.

I have tried rewriting the httpd.conf file in my Apache directory:

```
<Directory / "ftp://ftp.young1.org/academy/">
AllowOverride All
Require all denied
</Directory>
```

but to no avail. Is there a setting I have to change somewhere or additional code I have to place in to make it work? I am currently using a Xampp system on easyspace hosting.

Thanks,

Regards,

Robert Young

Comment: Is the rewrite module enabled on your web server?

Comment: Why are you serving up content via http using an ftp source? Highly inefficient...

Comment: Did you restart apache after changing the http.conf

Comment: `<Directory / "ftp://ftp.young1.org/academy/">` is invalid and would have given you an error it should be `<Directory /my/files/are/here/>`

Answer (score 0):

First check is you **mode_rewrite** module is enabled and confirm url rewriting is possible in your server. I hope you have a shered server,if its from godaddy url rewriting is not possible in my knowledge, please contact your customer service. because i have the same issue.

This link will really help you to correct your htaccess

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/